# In VS code one line of code shows no effect on await in nodejs

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Hi for the below code in the second await expression, for which the condition of job type is "two", VS code says await has no effect on the type of this expression.

However for the first line it is fine. The function implementation are also very similar. I am wondering why for one function alone vs code complains about this.

My code

```
if (jobtype === "one") {
      result = await exampleModel.getHrEmployees();
//     
    } else if (jobtype === "two") {
      result = await exampleModel.getSalesEmployees();
     
    }



const getHrEmployees = async () => {
  try {
    /** Populating the all active employee */
    // const sqlQuery = `SELECT * FROM .......`;

    let [result] = await bigQuery.query({
      query: sqlQuery,
      location: "EU"
    });

    /** returning a result object */
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    
  }
};


const getSalesEmployees = async () => {
  try {
    sqlQuery = `SELECT *FROM .....`;
    let [result] = await bigQuery.query({
      query: sqlQuery,
      location: "EU"
    });

    /** returning a result object */
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    
  }
};
```